# PHP file downloading through ftp, how to do this with utf8 in mind?

Tags: php, utf-8, ftp, fopen

There is a .TXT file with utf8 encoding (if i'm correct) on a external FTP server. I want to download this through a php script to my own ftp server. 
So i wrote a script, but when i look at the .txt, i see characters with a character that should be é looks like Ã«n. 
How can i do this correct? (also, if i run the same script again i want the **old file being replaced with a fresh new file**). This is my code:

```
<?php
// connecting with ftp server
$connection_id = ftp_connect('ftp.example.com'); 
// login with username and password
$login = ftp_login($connection_id, 'username', 'password'); 

// check connection
if ((!$connection_id) || (!$login)) {
   echo 'FTP connection has failed.';
   exit();
} else {
   echo 'Connection succeeded.';
}

$local_file = 'home/file.TXT'; 
$server_file = '/file.TXT';

// open file
$handle = fopen($local_file, 'w+');

// try to download txt file and save it locally
if(ftp_fget($connection_id, $handle, $server_file, FTP_BINARY, 0)) {
     echo 'Succesfully written to '.$local_file;
} else {
    echo 'Not succesfully downloaded!';
}

// close file handler
 fclose($handle);

//close the connection
ftp_close($connection_id);
?>
```

*Btw, does anbody know how to make life easier for showing code on stackoverflow by not indenting every single line by pressing on space for four times?*

Comment: `$local_file` or `$localfile`? Anyway, the FTP transfer is agnostic of the file content, you just get whatever is in the file. It seems like the file is encoded with UTF-8, so just treat it like that.

Comment: Which way do you "look" at the file after it is downloaded? Local editor? Webbrowser?

Comment: I look at it through a local editor ánd firefox. 
@Kerrek SB, thnx for noticing that!

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: @Orhan To indent the text by 4 spaces, just select the text block and press `ctrl`+`K`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bynary ftp transfer doesn't touch the character encoding of the text file. It copies at the bit level. It doesn't care what kind of data it transfers.

Have you tried to open both local and server file in your text viewer/editor?
If they look the same this could mean only two things:
1. The file is not UTF-8 on the server and this means that the copy will not be either.
2. Your editor/viewer doesn't support UTF-8 (or it doesn't know that the text should be displayed as UTF-8).

Comment: The file is utf-8 on the server, i don't know how to see if it actually is, but the server administrator told me so. 
Firefox can show utf-8 i guess?

Comment: It can, but make sure it interprets the file as utf8 (view menu - character encoding).

Answer (score 1):

You're using binary transfer, so it's downloading it from the server as it is. If the file is incorrect after the download, so it is on the server.

Comment: Binary transfer has nothing to do with it. The old (not even applicable anymore) binary-vs-text mode only affects line endings. UTF-8 is "binary-safe" in any conceivable way.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know lineendings are the only think affected by the mode.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP code is probably fine; it doesn't care what encoding the file is in, it's just copying the raw file data via FTP.

The more likely problem is that your TXT file reader doesn't handle UTF-8 encoding.  Have you checked your text file reader can display UTF-8 characters in other files?